# Uncaught reference error javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a form that takes values from the user and dropdown arrays to calculate a value and display it in an empty form field. This also requires a currency format function to show the value in USD. I can get everything to work just fine except the currency format.

The way the code is now shows `uncaught reference error`. If I take off the `inNum` function name out of the `onClick` event, the first part of the if statement works, displaying "Invalid Amount."

Any help with this conundrum is much appreciated! Thank You!

```js
function getShipping(inNum) {
  var product = document.getElementById("selected").value;
  var quantity = document.getElementById("textfield2").value;

  var salesT = product * quantity;

  var taxRate = document.getElementById("state").value;

  var taxTotal = taxRate * salesT;

  var shipping = document.getElementById("shipping").value;

  var totalBill = parseFloat(taxTotal) + parseFloat(salesT) + parseFloat(shipping);

  if (isNaN(inNum)) {
    //alert("result of isNaN" );   //The input amount is a non numeric string. It is or contains letters and/or spaces
    document.getElementById("total").value = "Invalid amount"
  } else {
    inNum = parseFloat(totalBill.inNum); //Convert input value into a floating point number.  toFixed() requires a number value to work with
    document.getElementById("total").value = parseFloat(totalBill) + inNum.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
  }

  //document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + totalBill;
}
```

```html
<h1 align=center>Calculate Your Order</h1>
<form name="frmProd" method="post" action="">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td width="53%">Select Product:</td>
      <td width="47%">
        <select size="1" name="product" id="selected">
          <option value="0" selected>Please Select a Product</option>
          <option value="1.99">Book</option>
          <option value=".99">Pen</option>
          <option value=".25">Pencil</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quantity:</td>
      <td>
        <input name="textfield2" type="text" id="textfield2" size="5">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shipping State (Tax Purposes):</td>
      <td>
        <select size="1" name=state id="state">
          <option selected value="0.06">Iowa</option>
          <option value="0.085">Illinois</option>
          <option value="0.7">Indiana</option>
          <option value="0.0">Other</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Delivery Method:</td>
      <td>
        <select size="1" name="shipping" id="shipping">
          <option value="9.50" selected>Standard UPS - 3 Days</option>
          <option value="6.50">US Mail - 5 Days</option>
          <option value="19.95">Overnight - 1 Day</option>
          <option value="0.0">Pickup</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Your Total is:</td>
      <td>
        <input name="total" value=$ 0.00 id="total">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate My Order Now!" name="submit" onClick="getShipping(inNum)">
    <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="button" value="Reset Form">
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Please read [ask], and how to create a [mcve] which demonstrates your error in a way that can be reproduced. Also, you may want to use the Stack Snippets feature (the button with `<>` in a page), which would create a snippet that runs in Stack Overflow.

Comment: you are calling a function and passing an argument that is not defined - where do you define inNum?

Answer (score 1):

```
inNum = parseFloat(totalBill.inNum);
```

`totalBill` is a number at this point, so it does not have a reference to `inNum`.

I'm not sure what you were trying to do with `inNum`, but getting rid of it altogether is probably the solution you're looking for:

```js
function getShipping() {
  var product = document.getElementById("selected").value;
  var quantity = document.getElementById("textfield2").value;

  var salesT = product * quantity;

  var taxRate = document.getElementById("state").value;

  var taxTotal = taxRate * salesT;

  var shipping = document.getElementById("shipping").value;

  var totalBill = parseFloat(taxTotal) + parseFloat(salesT) + parseFloat(shipping);

  if (isNaN(totalBill)) {
    //alert("result of isNaN" );   //The input amount is a non numeric string. It is or contains letters and/or spaces
    document.getElementById("total").value = "Invalid amount"
  } else {
    document.getElementById("total").value = parseFloat(totalBill).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
  }

  //document.getElementById("total").value = "$" + totalBill;
}
```

```html
<h1 align=center>Calculate Your Order</h1>
<form name="frmProd" method="post" action="">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td width="53%">Select Product:</td>
      <td width="47%">
        <select size="1" name="product" id="selected">
          <option value="0" selected>Please Select a Product</option>
          <option value="1.99">Book</option>
          <option value=".99">Pen</option>
          <option value=".25">Pencil</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quantity:</td>
      <td>
        <input name="textfield2" type="text" id="textfield2" size="5">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shipping State (Tax Purposes):</td>
      <td>
        <select size="1" name=state id="state">
          <option selected value="0.06">Iowa</option>
          <option value="0.085">Illinois</option>
          <option value="0.7">Indiana</option>
          <option value="0.0">Other</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Delivery Method:</td>
      <td>
        <select size="1" name="shipping" id="shipping">
          <option value="9.50" selected>Standard UPS - 3 Days</option>
          <option value="6.50">US Mail - 5 Days</option>
          <option value="19.95">Overnight - 1 Day</option>
          <option value="0.0">Pickup</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Your Total is:</td>
      <td>
        <input name="total" value=$ 0.00 id="total">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate My Order Now!" name="submit" onClick="getShipping()">
    <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="button" value="Reset Form">
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank You!